# Network Image Does Not Display Correct Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

I'm using `NetowrkImage` to display images from a URL, that does not include an image `extension`. I have also tried using `Image.network` but it gives a similar result.

**File Server Behaviour**

My server sends a placeholder image in response if the requested image is not available,  and I am getting the `placeholder` image with the correct URL for the image.

**Observation**

When I open the URL in the browser it opens the correct image, and when I add an extension `.jpeg` to the end of URL, it displays the placeholder image in the browser.

**Question**

Does `NetworkImage` add an extension to the source URL?

**Code**

```dart
Image.network(
         inventory.image!.url!,
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
          )
```

I'm struggling to make it work.

Comment: can you please share code?

Comment: The code includes just an ImageWidget, which I have added. This same URL, when opened in the browser displays an image.

Comment: doesn't make sense! Can you share the image link if it's public

Comment: It's not public.

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: None.
I'm getting an image that is displayed on the URL, if opened without user credentials.
In my browser and app I'm logged onto that server, in browser it displays the correct image, while in the app, it displays an image it would show in the browser when the user is not logged in.

Comment: ALHAMDULILLAH!
I found the cause of this. I'll write an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the question, the server responds with a placeholder image, if the `request` cannot be authenticated, that means the `sessoin_id` is not provided in the request header.

NetworkImage takes a parameter `headers`, and the custom HTTP interceptors won't work becuase this widget is making its own HTTP request, so the session_id has to be provided there.

```dart
Image.network(
          imageUrl,
          headers: { */ Auth Params have to be added here*/ },
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
         )
```

If you are using `Interceptors` and do not want to pass `headers` separately to `NetworkImage`, you should use `Image.memory` widget and wrap it inside a `FutureBuilder`.
Create a future that calls the image URL and returns `Uint8List`.

```dart
FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
      future: requestImageBytes,
      builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
            if (asyncSnapshot.connectionState ==
                         ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator();
                         );
                        }
                return Image.memory(
                         asyncSnapshot.data,
                         fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          );
                     })
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/646) .